# AAD - reply url specified in the request does not match for subdomain request

Tags: azure, active-directory

I have a website, let's say example.com.

The webapp is hosted on Azure.
There is an AAD app for login. The app seems correctly set up (reply URL is set to example.com).
Everything is fine when connecting directly to example.com.

However, if I try to reach example.com/data/123 directly (ie. I was not yet on example.com), I get redirected to the login page, but then the process fails with the error:

AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application

How is that possible?

Comment: In the second case `example.com/data/123` that isn't working, are you hitting the site over http instead of https?

Comment: May I know, what you have configured on web.config file (Hope this is c# based development) as reply url ?

Comment: - we use https
- no 'reply url' set in web.config

Comment: Can you paste the reply url specified in the request here? We will find the difference.

Comment: hi, the reply url in AAD? It is set to example.com